# Is this a statistic?

Tags: statistics, random-variables

If I have $n$ random variables, $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$.

Is this a statistic:

$$\Theta = 1/2(X_1+X_2)$$

I know the definition of statistic is the random variable represented by a function on my $n$ random variables, since I cannot think of a function on $n$ R.Vs that would yield this surely it is not a statistic?

Comment: The function $f_n(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n)=\frac{1}{2}\left( x_1+x_2\right)$ is certainly a function of $n$ variables.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou So surely it is a statistic, as are for example $|X_1|$ or $X_1$?

Comment: Even a constant function is a function, so a random variable represented by a constant function is also a statistic according to this definition.

Comment: @Hume2 what are non-examples of statistics?

Comment: $X$ isn't a statistic because it's not a function of random variable. $f(X)=X$ would be a statistic of one random variable. Note that constants and constant functions aren't the same thing. $f(a)=a$ isn't a statistic if $a$ isn't a random variable. Assuming that $X$ is a random variable and $a$ is not, $f(X,a)=aX$ is not a statistic.

Comment: @Hume2 Deterministic objects are random variables too.

Comment: @Hume2 Okay but something like $\Theta = f(X_1,...,X_n) = 12$ is a statistic, and the answer above states that $\Theta = f(X_1,...,X_n) = 1/2(X_1 +X_2)$ is also a function of $n$ random variables.

Comment: Yes, sure, it is also a statistic.

Comment: I think it might be clearer if a statistic was a  number calculated as a function of the actual observations rather than of the random variables. So $\frac12(x_1+x_2)$ would be a statistic (the average of the first two observations) while $\frac12(X_1+X_2)$ would be a random variable.  Like the distinction between an estimate and an estimator

Comment: Even $\Theta:=0$ is a statistic. A very trivial one, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or course $\frac{X_1+X_2}{2}$ is a Statistic!

to understand and detect immediately a Statistic: It is a function of the Data (of the data only...)

Example

$X_1,\dots X_5$ is a random sample drawn from a population $X\sim U(0;\theta)$

These are statistics:

- $T_1=\Sigma_i X_i$
- $T_2=\frac{1}{5}\Sigma_i X_i$
- $T_3=\max(X_i)$
- $T_4=\min(X_i)$
- $T_5=\{X_1,X_2\}$

On the contrary,

- $T_6=\frac{\max(X_i)}{\theta}$

is not a Statistic because is depends both from the data and from the parameter. Anyway $T_6$ has a very important Statistic meaning. What kind of quantity is it?